# How do you debug slowness in mysql

Tags: mysql, debugging, upgrade, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I have recently upgraded a system from mysql5.6 to mysql5.7 and I am experienceing significant lose of speed in the app.
Beside going over the available config values one by one and learn them + tweka them, Is there a way to identify/ debug the problem?
Google will give me info on how to use the slow query log, but that wont help, a I am not debugging a specific slow query, but rather a slownes that settms maybe from bad installation/configuration of the entire DB.

Comment: Could you give us more details about 'significant lose of speed'?

Comment: You start by looking at the execution plans of the queries you are using.

Comment: @walter Same query on a 5.6 installation is about as twice as fast, It is a query that does a large select from several tables and inserts the results into a new table. The write is the problem, queries which are read are being approx same speed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I might have not make it obvious, This question is not about optimizing specific query, it is about a speed lose between two version of mysql, I do not want to optimize the query, I want to optimize the server. I will check `explain` for significante difference between the two servers.